# how to use datatables search with the jquery-multiselect plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to use [jquery-multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) this plugin to handle the search in this plugin [jquery-datatables](http://datatables.net/)? I generate the Table with a server-side script. But I need to use the jquery-multiselect plugin for the search in datatables.

the code to load the table is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    url = 'lib/includes/load_table.php?text=test';
    mytable = $('#article').dataTable({
        oLanguage: {
            'sUrl': 'lib/components/datatables/src/de_DE.js'
        },
        'bFilter': true,
        'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
        'bProcessing': true,
        'bServerSide': true,
        'sAjaxSource': 'lib/includes/load_table.php',
        //'sDom' : '<"clear">tr'
    });
});
```

the load_table.php looks like this:

```
<?php
include('../common.php');

$output = array(
    'sEcho' => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    'iTotalRecords' => 57,
    'iTotalDisplayRecords' => 57,
    'aaData' => array()
);

$limit = 10;

$elements = array();
$elements[] = array("", 1);

$test = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0,".intval($_GET['iDisplayLength'])."";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    $test[] = array(
        $row["werkstoff"],
        $row["artikel"],
        $row["aussendurchmesser_1"],
        $row["wandstaerke_1"],
        $row["aussendurchmesser_2"],
        $row["wandstaerke_2"],
        $row["norm"],
        '<span class="currency">EUR</span> <span class="price">'.number_format($row["vkpreis"], "2", ",", "").'</span>',
        $_form->clickboxes("radio", "form[zeugnis".$row["id_artikel"]."]", $elements),
        $_form->clickboxes("radio", "form[zeugnis".$row["id_artikel"]."]", $elements),
        $_form->clickboxes("radio", "form[zeugnis".$row["id_artikel"]."]", $elements),
        '<i class="icon-question-sign"></i>',
        $_form->text("text", "form[value".$row["id_artikel"]."]", "40px").'
        <button class="button orange small shoppingcart" arID="'.$row["id_artikel"].'"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></button>
        <a href="'.modifyurl(ARTIKEL, "id=".$row["id_artikel"]."").'"><button class="button white small"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i></button></a>');
    $output["aaData"] = $test;
    }

echo $test = json_encode($output);
?>
```

and this is how the multiselect looks:

```
<h4>Werkstoffe</h4>
        <select class="multiselect" size="10">
            <option value="">1</option>
            <option value="">2</option>
            <option value="">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is indeed possible - How exactly do you want to use it? As checkbox-arrays? It is very unclear - there must be some reason to use multiselect you need to explain.

Comment: @davidkonrad I have a huge table with more than 15.000 entries. Each entry has a material which you can select from the multiselect with checkboxes to find the right entrys faster. example: in the multiselect field you have as material: lether and iron. In the table are 5000 entrys and 2500 have as material lether. When I select lether from the multiselect I want to display 2500 entrys with the material lether.

Comment: show your markup / code for the multiselect, then I'm sure it is possible to make it work with dataTables. There is not much to go further with :)

Comment: my code for the multiselect you can find here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EzzTZ/)

Comment: That is nice, but still no one can replicate your scenario. I can tell you how you react on multiselect and filter the dataTable afterwards, but who will ever learn of that? Your 3 lines of question? Show your code, elaborate your question - so other people in the future can benefit. That is what SO is about. Then you will get an answer.

Comment: In general you should show reproduceable code. Not link to your own website, not link to a jsfiddle or jsbin alone. Be concrete.

Comment: I added the code above ;)